# Handler not workig when device is locked screen

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

Activity is open when the device is lock screen but my problem is inside activity am using handler for showing Dialog its not working. Handler is working when my device is unlock then dialog is also showing.My problem is only when the device screen is unlock I want to start the handler inside the activity for showing dialog.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
       wind = this.getWindow();
       wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUA‌​RD); 
       wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCK‌​ED); 
       wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON‌​);  
       wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call); 
       mHandler_calldismiss=new Handler(); 
       mHandler_calldismiss.postDelayed(runnable,30000); }
```

Comment: post your code !

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        wind = this.getWindow();
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call);  mHandler_calldismiss=new Handler();
        mHandler_calldismiss.postDelayed(runnable,30000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an activity, Befor lock, it calls onPause() and after unlock , It calls onResume(). So you can write your handler code in the onResume() functions

1. The user opens an activity.
2. onCreated() is called
3. onStart() is called
4. onResume() is called
5. The user LOCKS the device onPause is called()
6. The user UNLOCKS the device onResume() is called

Comment: happy to help @Satyendra